Issues with Cucumber Tests After Splitting Microservice into Multi-Module Structure
We recently split our microservice into multiple modules to address performance issues. The structure now includes:

Common Module: A shared library (common) with common logic.

Main Module: The core module where most processing happens.

Visu Module: A separate module for functional needs related to visualization.


We are using Cucumber for testing. Here’s how our test setup looked before the split:
Cucumber Test Class (Previous Setup)
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features", plugin = "pretty", glue = "fr.***.***.commande.services")
    public class CucumberTest {
    }

Configuration Class (Previous Setup)
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
    @CucumberContextConfiguration
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    @Testcontainers
    public abstract class ApplicationTest {

        @ClassRule
        public static TestPostgresContainer postgres = TestPostgresContainer.getInstance();
    }

This setup worked perfectly before the refactoring. However, after restructuring the project into modules, we encountered the following error:
    "Provide a glue option or specify with either @CucumberContextConfiguration or @ContextConfiguration."

To resolve this, I tried centralizing all the configuration in one file and explicitly including the location of the configuration, step definitions, and the new common module as it is a dependency. Despite these attempts, the error persists.


    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = "classpath:features",
            plugin = {"pretty"})
    @CucumberContextConfiguration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
            "**.******.******.******.common",
            "**.******.******.******.traitement.services"
    })
    @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    @Testcontainers
    public class CucumberTest {
        @ClassRule
        public static TestPostgresContainer postgres = TestPostgresContainer
                .getInstance();
    }

This returns the following error :
    Errors: 
    [ERROR]   CucumberTest » StoppedByUser
    [ERROR]   Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@66019544 testClass = **.******.******.******.traitement.CucumberTest, locations = [], classes = [**.******.******.******.traitement.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [] .... (trancated) 

I have been stuck as i have been trying the few alternatives available to me (according to my current knowledge).

In your old setup you specified a glue in @CucumberOptions, but not in your new setup. That's probably your mistake. Cucumber use the glue to know where to look for step definitions and the @CucumberContextConfiguration annotated class.

To answer your question with certainty you'd have to share an overview of your project structure. Package names are important here.
